# Using class-local type aliases in a template base class list

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

In this code:

```
template <typename Pair>
struct EdgeRange :
  public std::pair<decltype(valueIter(std::declval<Pair>().first)),
                   decltype(valueIter(std::declval<Pair>().second))> {
  using EntryFirst  = decltype(valueIter(std::declval<Pair>().first));
  using EntrySecond = decltype(valueIter(std::declval<Pair>().second));

  EdgeRange(const Pair& p):
    std::pair<EntryFirst, EntrySecond>(valueIter(p.first), valueIter(p.second))
  {}
};
```

The `decltype` types are mentioned twice each. How can I eliminate this duplication without moving the types outside the class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`std::pair`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair) has typedefs for its two types, so you could just take advantage of those:

```
template <typename Pair>
struct EdgeRange :
  public std::pair<decltype(valueIter(std::declval<Pair>().first)),
                   decltype(valueIter(std::declval<Pair>().second))>
{
    using EntryFirst  = typename EdgeRange::first_type;
    using EntrySecond = typename EdgeRange::second_type;

    // ...
};
```

Comment: ... and similar for the ctor, you can use `EdgeRange::pair(...)` instead of naming the two member types, if that was the only purpose of defining those two typedefs.

Comment: Interesting. I wonder why `std::pair(...)` doesn't work in this context?